# Is there a way to get the System.Drawing.KnownColor collection in other language, like Spanish?

Tags: c#, colors, translate

I'm retrieving the collection of `System.Drawing.KnownColor` but I want to translate the color names. Is there a way to do it? I mean, I could translate all the colors one by one but, is there an easy way?

Comment: Like in all the in-built collections in .NET, the KnownColor collection has the same elements everywhere (no matter what language VS is in). Can you please clarify why are you asking this? Perhaps there is a workaround delivering what you want.

Comment: I want to list those colors in a ComboBox, but the language of the colors have to match the "ApplicationLanguage" (English or Spanish)

Comment: @varocarbas `KnownColor` is an enum not a collection

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Sorry for the error. When I say "collection" I usually talk generally (not meaning a exact .NET collection). But thanks for the correction anyway.

Comment: You might check out [google's](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest) or [bing's translate api](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis).  Google's cost money, Bing is free.

Comment: Google's is VERY easy to get started, Bing is a pain in the a$$.  Here is a [Bing Tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/gettingstarted1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform the translation manually. A `Dictionary` will help you to move between languages easily. Sample code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add(KnownColor.ActiveBorder.ToString(), "BordeActivo");
dict.Add(KnownColor.ActiveCaption.ToString(), "MensajeActivo");
dict.Add(KnownColor.ActiveCaptionText.ToString(), "TextoMensajeActivo");
//etc.    

bool languageIsEnglish = true;
foreach (string entry in dict.Keys)
{
    string curVal = entry;
    if (!languageIsEnglish)
    {
        curVal = dict[entry];
    }

    comboBox1.Items.Add(curVal);
}
```

Comment: You can use ResourceManager for this purpose, any number of language you can support easily

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you can use many things but I don't see any problem with the proposed dictionary (for small enough sizes is a very efficient solution). What problem do you see with what I have proposed?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel logically the proposed solution is meant for the specific situation (just two languages). With more languages, the loop populating the combobox wouldn't work either.

Comment: Ofcourse, no problem your solution can solve the problem. It is purely my suggestion not opposition. If you feel my suggestion is valid you can take that. though +1 for good workaround

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks. Your suggestion is much more scalable than the proposed solution and should be considered for more complicated situations (you cannot rely on a Dictionary to translate the whole vocabulary of 10 languages, logically). I am sure that your comment will be interesting for future readers, although don't think that should include it in my answer: it is a simple-solution answer (for a simple problem) for an OP precisely looking for making things quicker/easier, why complicating things further? Complicate things in the part meant for complication-seekers: the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a system using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and the [Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.compiler%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object to convert the known objects and their values into strings, whereby you can replace the property names programmatically, compile it on the fly, and load it in. I've used this approach before to do some wonky, hacky, just-for-fun kinds of replacements.

So basically just use [enum.GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx) and [enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) to get the names and actual values of the items in the enum. Then convert these to strings and recreate the code for an enum in a string, replacing the given names (in English) with the names you desire (in Spanish, I guess). Then pass this string to the compiler object, and go from there.

Comment: I think he's asking more about the translation than actually getting all the values.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I do have a List<String> with all the colors, but they are in English, I would like them to be in Spanish.

Comment: @NickLScott translate them into `Spanish` **manually** and store the result in a `Dictionary`, I don't think there is any library stuff doing the translation for you.

Comment: @KingKing there are too many colors in that collection, that's why I was asking for an easy way.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking you wanted to sort of replace/suplement the existing enum with a renamed version. Overcomplicating things here.

Comment: @NickLScott you still have to translate yourself, one of easy ways for you is **connect to some translation service** to get the translated string, otherwise, you have to prepare all the corresponding `Spanish` strings and store somewhere (in an XML file is OK).